# Getting a Pine-script error when trying to get lowest or highest values

Tags: pine-script

Hi I’m new to Pine Script, so please bear with me on the amateur level of the question
I was playing, in Version 5, with some Public Library  Darvas box code (from Version 3) and the code is as follows:

```
boxp=input(5, "BOX LENGTH")

LL=lowest (low,boxp)
k1=highest(high,boxp)
k2=highest(high,boxp-1)
k3=highest(high,boxp-2)
```

The keyword “input” is in blue but the “lowest” and “highest” functions are not recognized and I get an error "Could not find function or function reference 'lowest'." (same for highest).

These lines of  code are used in several other Public Library functions..

Please guide  me how I can get around this – I looked up the migration manuals but did not find anything useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In v5, these functions [were renamed to `ta.lowest()` and `ta.highest()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html#all-variable-function-and-parameter-name-changes).

You can use the `Ctrl + Space` hotkey to see the autocomplete suggestions, try writing `lowest` and pressing the hotkeys and it'll suggest you `ta.lowest` automatically.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the guidance